# javascript function need to be continue after settimeout

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function; from that am calling a delay function.

```
function(){
  // code

  doDelay();

  // some other functionality....
}

function doDelay(){
   setTimeout(function() {alert("after wait");}, 10000);
}
```

after waiting 10 seconds alert is coming `after wait`. but its not again continue the `some other functionality....` of my main function.. After delay I want to execute the remaining functionality. How can I do that?

Comment: Put `some other functionality...` inside the function in the `setTimeout`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363622/jquery-run-function-after-settimeout

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function does not delay execution. Instead, it schedules a function to be executed at a later time. To do what you want you need to change your code to this:

```
function(){
...
...
    doDelay(function(){

      some other functionality....

    });
}

function doDelay(callback){
    setTimeout(function() {callback()}, 10000);
}
```

Indeed, javascript already has a doDelay function. It's called `setTimeout`:

```
function(){
...
...

    setTimeout(function(){

      some other functionality....

    },10000);
}
```

If you want the outer function to also delay execution of code that comes after it, you also need to pass a callback to it:

```
function foo (callback){
...
...
    doDelay(function(){

      some other functionality....

      callback();

    });
}
```

So that, for example, it allows you to rewrite something like this:

```
foo();
// do other stuff after foo...
```

to this:

```
foo(function(){
    // do other stuff after foo...
});
```

You basically need to restructure your logic around callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you wrap the other functionality in another function, then from your SetTimeout call that function?

```
 function(){
  doDelay();
}

function doDelay(){
  setTimeout(function() {alert("after wait");andTheRest();}, 10000);
}

function andTheRest(){
  //Rest of the stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doDelayAndThenContinue(){
          setTimeout(function() {alert("after wait"); 
              //do other functionality here
          }, 10000);

     }
```

Remove the do other functionality from main method and put in setTimeout